# A relationship between stopping times and their $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: stopping-times

I'm studying [Stochast integration and stochastic differential equation by Protter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540003134) and got confused by the solution of the very first exercise provided [here](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~protter/books.html).

So

> **Exercise 1.**  Let $S,T$ be stopping times, $S \leq T$ a.s. Show $\mathcal{F}_S \subset \mathcal{F}_T$

The provided solution starts like this:

> $\forall A \subset \mathcal{F}_S, \forall t \geq 0, A \cap \{T \leq t\} = 
>  (A \cap \{S \leq t\}) \cap \{T \leq t\}$ since $\{T \leq t\} \subset \{S \leq t\}$

But $S \leq T$ **almost surely**. It means that there is a set $N \subset \mathcal{F}_0$ (usual hypotheses) with $\mathbf{P}(N) = 0$ such that $ \forall \omega \in N : S(\omega) > T(\omega)$ so $\exists t_0 : \{T \leq t_0\} \not\subset \{S \leq t_0\}$

Thus the start of the proof need to be corrected like that:

$\forall A \subset \mathcal{F}_S, \forall t \geq 0, A \cap \{T \leq t\} = 
 (A \cap (\{S \leq t\} \cup N)) \cap \{T \leq t\}$ since $\{T \leq t\} \subset \{S \leq t\} \cup N$

The rest of the solution works if we replace $\{S \leq t\}$ by $\{S \leq t\} \cup N$:

> Since  $A \cap (\{S \leq t\} \cup N) \subset \mathcal{F}_t$ (since $N \subset \mathcal{F}_0 \subset \mathcal{F}_t$) and $\{T \leq t\} \subset \mathcal{F}_t$  we have $A \cap \{T \leq t\} \subset \mathcal{F}_t$ so $\mathcal{F}_S \subset \mathcal{F}_T$

Am I right or it is an unnecessary complication of the correct solution?

Comment: They probably assume early on that $\mathcal F_0$ (hence, and every other sigma-algebra considered) is complete, that is, that it contains every $N$ such that there exists $A$ in $\mathcal F$ such that $P(A)=0$ and $N\subseteq A$.

Comment: Yes, they do say that. Would it be correct then to assume that we can simply ignore all those $\omega \in A$ because they belongs to all $\sigma-$algebras and thus can not impact the proof?

Comment: Hmmm... those $\omega$s in $A\subseteq\Omega$ certainly do not belong to the sigma-algebras on $\Omega$.

Comment: Ok, they belong to "all $\sigma$-algebras in the given filtration $(F_t)_{0 \leq t \leq \infty}$ since $F_0$ contains all P-null sets. Right?

Comment: No, $\omega$ in $\Omega$ belongs to no sigma-algebra on $\Omega$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.  But anyway thank you for pointing to completenece - I believe that's what I missed.

Comment: The point is basic: a sigma-algebra on $\Omega$ is made of subsets of $\Omega$, not of elements of $\Omega$.

Comment: Actually, the fact that probability space is complete (you meant probability space, not sigma-algebra, above, right?)  does not help.  $\{T \leq t\} \not \subset  \{S \leq t\}$ and you have to extend the solution with $N$ as described above.